# Is it possible for a NSObject subclass to "hook in" to every property access

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I have an object that I serialize for saving to disk, and occasionally new properties get added when upgrading my app (think app prefs). A new property would not exist on an old object, so naturally `[myObj myNewProperty]` would evaluate to nil. I want to change this so I can return something relevant, and preferably do so without overriding the getter for every property. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Look at the runtime programming guide

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default value when decoding your object:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self.myNewProperty = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myNewProperty"];
    if(!self.myNewProperty)
    {
        self.myNewProperty = ...(The new value here!);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That certainly works but I'm looking for a more automatic/reusable approach where I can refer to properties dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can record the version while serializing and get back while deserializing then you can check if you are accessing old version object or a new one with additional properties like below

```
#define kVersionKey @"Version"

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeInt:1 forKey:kVersionKey];
   // other encoding
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    int i=[decoder decodeIntForKey:kVersionKey];
   if (i==1) {
        // set your new property
    }
    // other decodings
}
```